# Is there a description of how __cmp__ works for dict objects in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I've been trying to make a `dict` subclass inheriting from `UserDict.DictMixin` that supports non-hashable keys.  Performance isn't a concern.  Unfortunately, Python implements some of the functions in `DictMixin` by trying to create a dict object from the subclass.  I can implement these myself, but I am stuck on `__cmp__`.

I cannot find a succinct description of the logic used by the built-in `__cmp__` for the dict class.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are asking how comparing dictionaries works, it is this:

- To compare dicts A and B, first compare their lengths.  If they are unequal, then return cmp(len(A), len(B)).
- Next, find the key adiff in A that is the smallest key for which `adiff not in B or A[adiff] != B[adiff]`.  (If there is no such key, the dicts are equal.)
- Also find the smallest key bdiff in B for which `bdiff not in A or A[bdiff] != B[bdiff]`.
- If adiff != bdiff, then return cmp(adiff, bdiff).  Else return cmp(A[adiff], B[bdiff]).

In pseudo-code:

```
def smallest_diff_key(A, B):
    """return the smallest key adiff in A such that adiff not in B or A[adiff] != B[bdiff]"""
    diff_keys = [k for k in A if k not in B or A[k] != B[k]]
    return min(diff_keys)

def dict_cmp(A, B):
    if len(A) != len(B):
        return cmp(len(A), len(B))
    try:
        adiff = smallest_diff_key(A, B)
    except ValueError:
        # No difference.
        return 0
    bdiff = smallest_diff_key(B, A)
    if adiff != bdiff:
        return cmp(adiff, bdiff)
    return cmp(A[adiff], b[bdiff])
```

This is translated from the 2.6.3 implementation in dictobject.c.

Comment: Did you know that by reading the source for `dict_compare` (http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c) or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the info. (PS. I guess this means the behavior of `dict.__cmp__` may vary across implementations. :-/ )

Comment: @NedBatchelder Can we format text like [this in algo form](http://codepad.org/bWwkRFRA), I believe it would be easy to grasp.    Presently it is very inconvenient in reading. Btw thanks this is very good answer.

Comment: Some of the deviations from the original routine were bugging me, so I edited the answer to match dict_compare a bit more closely. (I didn't bother with the edge case handling for when a comparison mutates the dict, and the `except ValueError` will do the wrong thing if a comparison throws a ValueError. Unlike the original C, I can't return NULL as a sentinel, and None is already a valid return value.) If I got something wrong, feel free to revert or edit again.

Comment: If you want some example, you may look at `https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-cmp-function-of-a-dictionary-work` BTW, python3 is no longer support `cmp`

Comment: This slower but simpler (?) function gives the same answer: `cmp = lambda A, B: (A > B) - (A < B) if not hasattr(A, '__keys__') else cmp(len(A), len(B)) if len(A) != len (B) else ([cmp(adiff, bdiff) if adiff != bdiff else cmp(A[adiff], B[bdiff]) for adiff, bdiff in zip(sorted(A.keys()), sorted(B.keys())) if adiff != bdiff or A[adiff] != B[bdiff]] + [0])[0]`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the Mapping ABC from the [collections](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes) package.  It is available in 2.6 and up.  You just inherit from collections.Mapping and implement the `__getitem__`, `__contains__`, and `__iter__` methods.  You get everything else for free.

Answer (score 0):

There is a description of `__cmp__` [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__), but I think the important thing to note is that `__cmp__` is only used if the “rich comparison” methods, such as `__lt__` and `__eq__` are not defined. Moreover, in Python3, `__cmp__` is removed from the language. So perhaps eschew `__cmp__` altogether and just define `__lt__` and `__eq__`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to make the interface match 2.4 dict's (work requirement).  I'll probably do a full on 3.x port of this code later.