# Default key when sorting list of dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting

When sorting on a list of dictionaries, it is possible to ensure consistency and the desired sort-order by specifying one or more keys.

For example, given a list L:

```
L = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'b':1, 'a':2}]
sorted(L, key=lambda dic:dic['a'])
```

returns

> [ {'a': 1, 'b': 2} , {'a': 2, 'b': 1} ]

Similarly,

```
sorted(L, key=lambda dic:dic['b'])
```

returns

> [ {'a': 2, 'b': 1} , {'a': 1, 'b': 2} ]

When not providing a key, i.e. just using `sorted(L)` I am observing a sort order identical to the first sort expression. **How exactly is a key chosen when not provided?**

**Background:**
My final goal is to write a generic comparator (`self.__eq__`) for a custom class, the basis of equality for which will be a number of properties one or more of which may be list of dictionaries. Since it is difficult to provide a sort key as  fields within the dictionary that forms the list may not be known beforehand I was considering skipping the use of a key altogether to force the default. My gut feeling is that `sorted` will yield the same result for a compound type regardless of original order in the absence of a key, but I haven't found any documentation to support this. Can someone explain?

**Edit**: I cannot understand why this was marked as a duplicate of the solution to [explanation for `dict.__cmp__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484293/is-there-a-description-of-how-cmp-works-for-dict-objects-in-python-2) ? I am trying to sort a list, not a dictionary. I do not care how the constituent dictionaries are ordered but what matters is the place of any dictionary in the list for list vs list comparison. With a normal list once could do `set(L1)==set(L2)` to compare contents, however, my goal is try and compare two lists when the contents are dictionaries and this is why I need to sort them.

Comment: When calling `sorted(L)`, the order in which the elements of `L` are arranged depends on how `__cmp__` is implemented on them. In your case, the elements are dicts, hence the order depends on the behaviour of `dict.__cmp__`. Hence, the question was closed as a duplicated.

Comment: Okay, thanks for adding this. I think this would have better a better answer than the question being marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

use `def __cmp__(self,other)` for a comparator.

dictionaries by definition have no order.... therefor there sort behavior is undefined without further specification, you cannot rely on anything ...(actually I sort of retract this given the potential dupe target in the comments of OP ... I still say you should not sort dictionaries without explicitly telling it how you want it sorted)

```
sorted([(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8)])
```

will sort on the first item in the list ... in the event of a tie it will sort on the second item in the list and so on

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. Please note that I am not trying to sort a dictionary but a list here. I can't see why this is a duplicate as you marked

Comment: that dupe explains how a dictionary is compared to another dictionary ... this answer is one of many that explains how lists are sorted .... I also recommend using `def __cmp__` to implement your comparator on a custom class(as opposed to `self.__eq__`) ... if neither answers your question perhaps you could try rephasing the question somehow...

Comment: I think the first comment, added later on the question explained how a default key is chosen : I guess by going down the compound data type depth wise, so `__cmp__` is attempted on dict which is undefined. However, I was inclined to implement rich comparison `__eq__` as I only see the application for `==` not `>=` or `<=`. The class is a genome. I kind of agree with the philosophy in http://gerg.ca/blog/post/2012/python-comparison/