# Sorting list of dictionaries---what is the default behaviour (without key parameter)?

Tags: python, sorting

I m trying to sort a list of dict using `sorted`

```
>>> help(sorted)
Help on built-in function sorted in module __builtin__:

sorted(...)
    sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list
```

I have just given list to sorted and it sorts according to `id`.

```
>>>l = [{'id': 4, 'quantity': 40}, {'id': 1, 'quantity': 10}, {'id': 2, 'quantity': 20}, {'id': 3, 'quantity': 30}, {'id': 6, 'quantity': 60}, {'id': 7, 'quantity': -30}]
>>> sorted(l) # sorts by id
[{'id': -1, 'quantity': -10}, {'id': 1, 'quantity': 10}, {'id': 2, 'quantity': 20}, {'id': 3, 'quantity': 30}, {'id': 4, 'quantity': 40}, {'id': 6, 'quantity': 60}, {'id': 7, 'quantity': -30}]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l # sorts by id
[{'id': -1, 'quantity': -10}, {'id': 1, 'quantity': 10}, {'id': 2, 'quantity': 20}, {'id': 3, 'quantity': 30}, {'id': 4, 'quantity': 40}, {'id': 6, 'quantity': 60}, {'id': 7, 'quantity': -30}]
```

Many example of `sorted` says it requires `key` to sort the list of dict. But I didn't give any `key`. Why it didn't sort according to `quantity`? How did it choose to sort with `id`? 
I tried another example with name & age,

```
>>> a
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'shyam'}, {'age': 30,'name': 'ram'}, {'age': 15, 'name': 'rita'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'sita'}]
>>> sorted(a) # sorts by age
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'shyam'}, {'age': 5, 'name':'sita'}, {'age': 15, 'name': 'rita'}, {'age': 30, 'name': 'ram'}]

>>> a.sort() # sorts by age
>>> a
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'shyam'}, {'age': 5, 'name':'sita'}, {'age': 15, 'name': 'rita'}, {'age': 30, 'name': 'ram'}]
```

Here it sorts according to `age` but not `name`. What am I missing in default behavior of these method?

Comment: Aside: in modern (i.e. not outdated :-) versions of Python, you'll get `TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()`..

Comment: you may check the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484293/is-there-a-description-of-how-cmp-works-for-dict-objects-in-python-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From some [old Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/comparisons.html):

> Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted (key, value) lists compare equal. Outcomes other than equality are resolved consistently, but **are not otherwise defined**.
>
> Earlier versions of Python used lexicographic comparison of the sorted (key, value) lists, but this was very expensive for the common case of comparing for equality. An even earlier version of Python compared dictionaries by identity only, but this caused surprises because people expected to be able to test a dictionary for emptiness by comparing it to {}.

Ignore the default behaviour and just provide a `key`.

Answer (score 0):

By default it will compare against the first difference it finds.  If you are sorting dictionaries this is quite dangerous (consistent yet undefined).

Pass a function to `key=` parameter that takes a value from the list (in this case a dictionary) and returns the value to sort against.

```
>>> a
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'shyam'}, {'age': 30,'name': 'ram'}, {'age': 15, 'name': 'rita'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'sita'}]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda d : d['name']) # sorts by name
[{'age': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 30, 'name': 'ram'}, {'age': 15, 'name': 'rita'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'shyam'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'sita'}]
```

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

The key parameter is quite powerful as it can cope with all sorts of data to be sorted, although maybe not very intuitive.