# Comparing Dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program where I compare two strings' characters. I'm trying to make it where the second string has to have the same characters as the first.

So if the first string is `"Hello"` and the second is `"Helloo"` it will turn out as false, but if the second string is `"ello"` it will be true.

I have both strings in their own dictionary that counts the amount of each character. I'm trying to do this :

```
if Dictionary1 >= Dictionary2 :
        print('True')
```

I don't know if I am thinking of this in an incorrect fashion, but I can't get this to work. I'm still relatively new to Python so if possible, please keep the explanations simple. Thanks !

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, at the moment it's not enough to give a concrete answer. Are you saying you have a dictionary like `Dictionary1 = {'helloo': 6}`? You should provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I have it as String1 = `input('Enter Text')  String 2 = input('Text').`  Then each is set to a dictionary and counted for characters.

Comment: But that doesn't relate to dictionaries. Please edit sufficient information into the original question so we can see what you're actually doing.

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3484456/424173) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is a high performance alternative for your counting `dict`:

```
> from collections import Counter

> string_1 = 'hello'
> string_2 = 'ello'
> c1, c2  = map(Counter, (string_1, string_2))
# c1, c2  = Counter(string_1), Counter(string_2)
> all(c1[c] >= c2[c] for c in c2)
True
```

You must make sure that for every letter in `string_2`, this letter's count in `string_1` is greater or equal to its count in `string_2`. You cannot just compare two dictionaries via `>=`

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> str1 = "Hello"
>>> str2 = "ello"
>>> print (str2 in str1)
True
>>> print (str1 in str2)
False
```