# Why min({1},{0}) returns {1}

Tags: python, min

min() function should return the smallest of the numbers given. Then why

```
min({0},{1})
```

returns {0}, while

```
min({1},{0})
```

returns {1}?

Comment: My question would be why don't dictionaries behave similarly?..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis In Python 3 `dict` is an unorderably type, but in Python 2, they are compared https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484293/is-there-a-description-of-how-cmp-works-for-dict-objects-in-python-2

Answer (score 7):

In python sets are compared based on whether or not one **is a subset** of the other.

None is a subset of the other, so `<` gives `False` in all cases, so the first one is returned.

So `{1}<{0}` gives `False` just like `{2}<{1}` gives `False` and `{2}<{3,4,5}` gives False.
However `{1,2}<{1,3,2}` gives `True`.
This means there is no **total order** defined on sets.

Comment: this is inncorrect `min({1,3,4,5},{0,2})` returns `{1, 3, 4, 5}`, which is of the smaller size

Comment: My original answer was indeed incorrect. I edited the answer to give the correct answer: Set compare based on `is_subset` relation.

Answer (score 5):

The [comparison operators for sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) check for "subset" not for numerical comparisons:

> `set < other`
>
> Test whether the set is a proper subset of other, that is, set <= other and set != other.

And both your sets are disjoint so `{0} < {1} == False` and `{1} < {0} == False` so it will always return the "first" set you put into `min`.

Answer (score 4):

Because these are **sets**, not **numbers**.

Moreover, it should return {1}, not 1, as you can see here:

```
>>> min({0},{1})
set([0])
>>> min({1},{0})
set([1])
```

That means that it will return the *set*, not the *number*.

Comment: It isn't true that sets are compared by size - eg, `min({2,3, 4}, {1,2})` is `{2,3,4}`.

Comment: @lvc you are right, answer updated! =) Is it OK now?

Comment: I believe it's better to paste code instead of image, it would be more readable.

Comment: @vishes_shell you got it!