# Why can't I sort a list of dicts in 3.x? Why do I get "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'"?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I had a perfectly functioning sort by value in python 2.7 but I'm trying to upgrade to python 3.6 and I get that error:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Here is my code

```
server_list = []

for server in res["aggregations"]["hostname"]["buckets"]:
    temp_obj = []
    temp_obj.append({"name":server.key})        
    temp_obj.append({"stat": server["last_log"]["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"][system].stat})
    server_list.append(temp_obj)
    server_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)
```

Why it's considered as a dict when I declare my server_list as a list. How can I make it sort by my name attribute?

Comment: In Python 2, for dictionaries with equal keys, it'll compare on values of the 'smallest' key between them, see [Is there a description of how \_\_cmp\_\_ works for dict objects in Python 2?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3484293). So here, just sort on the `server.key` value.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Python 2's dictionary sort order was [quite involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484293/is-there-a-description-of-how-cmp-works-for-dict-objects-in-python-2) and poorly understood. It only happened to work because Python 2 tried to make everything orderable.

For your specific case, with `{'name': ...}` dictionaries with a single key, the ordering was determined by the value for that single key.

In Python 3, where dictionaries are no longer orderable (together with many other types), just use that value as the sorting key:

```
server_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]['name'], reverse=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using itemgetter from operator.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_list = sorted(list, key=itemgetter('<dict_key>'))
```

Example:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

list = [
    {"name": "John Smith", "email": "john.smith@example.com", "address": "123 Main St, Anytown, USA"},
    {"name": "Jane Doe", "email": "jane.doe@example.com", "address": "456 Elm St, Anytown, USA"},
    {"name": "Bob Johnson", "email": "bob.johnson@example.com", "address": "789 Oak St, Anytown, USA"}
]
print('LIST:')
for row in list:
  print(row)

sorted_list = sorted(list, key=itemgetter('name'))

print('SORTED LIST:')
for row in sorted_list:
  print(row)
```

Console:

```
LIST:
{'name': 'John Smith', 'email': 'john.smith@example.com', 'address': '123 Main St, Anytown, USA'}
{'name': 'Jane Doe', 'email': 'jane.doe@example.com', 'address': '456 Elm St, Anytown, USA'}
{'name': 'Bob Johnson', 'email': 'bob.johnson@example.com', 'address': '789 Oak St, Anytown, USA'}
SORTED LIST:
{'name': 'Bob Johnson', 'email': 'bob.johnson@example.com', 'address': '789 Oak St, Anytown, USA'}
{'name': 'Jane Doe', 'email': 'jane.doe@example.com', 'address': '456 Elm St, Anytown, USA'}
{'name': 'John Smith', 'email': 'john.smith@example.com', 'address': '123 Main St, Anytown, USA'}
```

All credit to [@BrandonJacobson](https://www.youtube.com/@BrandonJacobson), for the explanation in his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2hacvwCjQA&ab_channel=BrandonJacobson)

Answer (score -1):

```
data = {"page": 1, "per_page": 6, "total": 12, "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
        {"id": 1, "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in", "first_name": "George", "last_name": "Bluth",
         "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"},
        {"id": 2, "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in", "first_name": "Janet", "last_name": "Weaver",
         "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"},
        {"id": 3, "email": "emma.wong@reqres.in", "first_name": "Emma", "last_name": "Wong",
         "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"},
        {"id": 4, "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in", "first_name": "Eve", "last_name": "Holt",
         "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"},
        {"id": 5, "email": "charles.morris@reqres.in", "first_name": "Charles", "last_name": "Morris",
         "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"},
        {"id": 6, "email": "tracey.ramos@reqres.in", "first_name": "Tracey", "last_name": "Ramos",
         "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"}
    ],
"support": {"url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
"text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}

mydata=sorted(data['data'],key=lambda x: x['id'], reverse=True)
print(mydata)
```