# Cannot raise APIException from Django ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-debug-toolbar

I have a method in a `ViewSet` where I want to validate that `request.data` is a list. If it is not, I would like to raise a `ParseError()`.

However, my code crashes when I actually raise said `ParseError` and I don't understand why. It is a subclass of `APIException`, which the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#exception-handling-in-rest-framework-views) states to be handled automatically.

```
# views.py
class MyViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    ...

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path='bulk-create')
    def bulk_create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Assert that request.data is a list of objects
        if not isinstance(request.data, list):
            raise ParseError("Expected the data to be in list format.")

        # Actually process incoming data
        ...
```

Calling the route with anything other than a list correctly triggers my `if` statement, but instead of returning a proper response with `status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`, the server crashes and I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366216553Z   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366221178Z     response = get_response(request)
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366223345Z   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 67, in __call__
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366225470Z     panel.generate_stats(request, response)
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366238220Z   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/request.py", line 30, in generate_stats
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366240470Z     "post": get_sorted_request_variable(request.POST),
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366346803Z   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/debug_toolbar/utils.py", line 227, in get_sorted_request_variable
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366352511Z     return [(k, variable.getlist(k)) for k in sorted(variable)]
2022-05-17T12:23:45.366354803Z TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Because of the error log, I suspect that the `django-debug-toolbar` got something to do with my problem. I have already tried moving it to every position in my middleware config, but that did not solve my problem.

```
# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_currentuser.middleware.ThreadLocalUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'rollbar.contrib.django.middleware.RollbarNotifierMiddleware',
]
```

**EDIT**: I understand that a sort fails at some point, but why is that sort happening in the first place?

**EDIT 2**: The people over at `django-debug-toolbar` helped me confirm, that it is the JSON formatted as array that clashes with the library when raising an exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695479/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-dict-and-dict)

Comment: Partially. I understand that somewhere in the code a sort fails, but why is the debug-toolbar involved in the first place?

Comment: I think that a dict is pretty much always expected from `request.POST`. If so, I think the debug toolbar tries to sort the values, but here since it's a list of dict, it tries to order dict, whch cannot be done without providing the sort key. submitting an object with a single key, which holds a list of dict should solve it maybe?

Comment: @jkoestinger Yep, that's basically what I resorted to. Thank you for the suggestion! The team at django-debug-toolbar fixed their implementation, but I was seeing similar errors when testing as well. Looks like top-level lists in JSON are not handled gracefully in many libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the awesome people at `django-debug-toolbar`, the library can now handle top-level arrays in `POST.data` as well. https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/pull/1624

Sadly, I ran directly into the same issue with Django's testing system...

```
# test_with_error.py

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class DonationBulkCreateRouteTestCase(APITestCase):
    def test_route_permissions(self):
        self.client.post(
            path="/bulk-create/",
            data=json.dumps([], default=json_serializer)
        )

# log.txt

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 245, in encode_multipart
    for (key, value) in data.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

So, although top-level arrays are valid JSON, I decided to wrap my data in an additional object, in which I pass the list. This has the additional benefit of being easier to extend in the future, because I can freely add keys without breaking existing code.